# Cannot make rails spec for a request working : `undefined method 'call' for #<App:`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying make the specs work on a project. There was a setup for specs but was not maintain.

I have a simple post for a `request spec`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Cars API', type: :request do
  let(:organization) { Fabricate(:organization, owner: user) }
  let(:app)          { Fabricate(:app, organization: organization, owner: user) }
  let(:user)         { Fabricate(:user) }

  before do
    #login_api(user)
  end

  describe 'create' do
    describe 'car type' do
      it 'should create a car of type CarType1' do
        expect(Car.count).to eql(0)
        id = '123'
        post("/api/1/organization/#{id}/cars")
        expect(Car.count).to eql(1)

        car = Car.first

        expect(car.type).to eql(Car::CarType1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I get

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #<App:0x007fee64557080>>
```

I've tried to debug the issue but with no luck. 
The issue happens at the line `post("/api/1/organization/#{id}/cars")`. 
Where might the problem be ?

Comment: why are you hardcoding the `id` as `123` ?

Comment: @Sasi the example is extracted from a larger code

Answer (score 6):

I had such problem ;) (and spent several hours for debugging sources)

Try to rename `app` to `ap` or similar variable.

```
# "bad" name
let(:app)          { ... }

# "better" name
let(:ap)          { ... }
# or 
let(:my_app)      { ... }
```

As I understood the problem in variable name when RSpec initializes your lazy block `let`. Not sure but I think at that moment `App` has already initialized and RSpec send method `call` not to block from `let` but to another object.

Note: you can use before block and use instance variable `@app`

Answer (score 4):

This issue is occuring because you are overriding the Rails `app` variable. Rename the variable to something else. It will work.

By default in rails, `app` variable is your Rails application which has `call` method that will be invoked whenever your application receives any request from Rack middleware.